# label as dynamic navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Made label to had value from database and linked it . but the problem was it had only one value and i want it keep value when navigation thought site as.

x>y>z>....

this is my code

<

if (Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] != null)
        {

```
        Banar.ImageUrl = "Handlers/Banner.ashx?Category_Id=" + Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] + "";
        using
    (SqlConnection conn = Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Navcategory";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Category_Id", Request.QueryString["Category_Id"]));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {

                    LblNavigaton.Visible = true;

                    LblNavigaton.Text = dr[i].ToString();
                    NavHref.HRef = "ListView.aspx?Category_Id=" + Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] + "";

            }

        }
    }
    else if (Request.QueryString["ProductCategory_Id"] != null)
    {
        Banar.ImageUrl = "Handlers/ProCatBanner.ashx?ProductCategory_Id=" + Request.QueryString["ProductCategory_Id"] + "";
        using
        (SqlConnection conn = Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "NavProductcategory";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@ProductCategory_Id", Request.QueryString["ProductCategory_Id"]));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                LblNavigaton.Visible = true;
                LblNavigaton.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
                NavHref.HRef = "ListView.aspx?ProductCategory_Id=" + Request.QueryString["ProductCategory_Id"] + "";
            }
            else
            {
                LblNavigaton.Visible = true;
                LblNavigaton.Text = Page.Title;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Assuming this application is being written in ASP.NET C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could retrieve the value every time you load a new page, or pass it as a URL parameter, or read up about [cross-page posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the value in `LblNavigaton.Text` "*throughout*" the site while user is logged in, then you can use the `Session` in that case. For instance like:

```
Session["LblNavigaton.Text"] = LblNavigaton.Text;
```